# Extend HTTP - Redirect when returns unauthorized

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to redirect to the login page when I get an 401 http status.
Fist attemp was:

```
public getPatients(extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Array<models.Patient>> {
const path = this.basePath + '/api/patient';

let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
let headerParams = this.defaultHeaders;
let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headerParams,
    search: queryParameters
};

return this.httpInterceptor.request(path, requestOptions)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        if (response.status === 204) {
            return undefined;
        } else {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
            return response.json();
        }
    });
```

}

But when I get the 401, I does not enter to the map function, it gives an unauthorized error in the browser.

So reading some posts, there's a way to extend the http service, seems to be the correct way, but I'm getting some issues when I try to instantiate http dependencies on app.module.ts. In my case I only need to rewrite the interceptor method, but I put all the code if someone else need other part.

Here is my http extension:

```
import { Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    };

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    };

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
    };

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    };

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    };

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    };

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return options;
    };

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status == 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }
};
```

In my app.module.ts I have to add this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PatientsComponent } from './pacientes/pacientes.component';
import { HttpInterceptor }  from '../api/api/HttpInterceptor';
import { RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
const routes: Routes = [

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    routing,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PatientsComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    HttpInterceptor,
    RequestOptions 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

All good by now, but when I try to use the new httpInterceptor service I created, importing it and adding it to the constructor and replace http instance for my new http interceptor instance, I get a No provider for ConnectionBackend, I try to add ConnectionBackend to providers but it says 'types of property providers are incompatible'. Then I try to add httpInterceptor but I get Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?).

So in summary there must be a way to extend http method correctly or handle the 401 in another way..
How can I do that, is there some tutorial, link or something to take a look?

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version rc6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no provider registered with the token `ConnectionBackend`. What you can do though is use a factory when you configure the interceptor

```
providers:    [
  { 
    provide: HttpInterceptor,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, router: Router) => {
      return new HttpInterceptor(backend, options, router);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router ]
  }
]
```

I've tested this with your code, and it should work.

Comment: I'm using the http to make request but I have to instanciate this new http HttpInterceptor and instead of this.http.request... I use this.http.httpInterceptor. I thought that using that factory will not require to replace the http for my HttpInterceptor, that it will just use it. Is there some way to not replace and tell angular to use always my HttpInterceptor?

Comment: Use `provide: Http`

Comment: If that still doesn't work (it's still using the normal Http), then you probably need to get rid of the `HttpModule` import, and provide all the dependencies yourself that `Http` depends on. You can look at the source for [HttpModule](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/http/src/http_module.ts#L46)

Comment: Do you mean this? providers:    [
  { 
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, router: Router) => {
      return new HttpInterceptor(backend, options, router);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router ]
  }
] When I do that it says that is no provider to HttpInterceptor

Comment: Aren't you trying to use `Http`, not `HttpInterceptor`? The `provide` supplies the _token_ for which you can inject with. If you change it to `Http`, you can no longer inject `HttpInterceptor`. But the actual `Http` object should still be your custom interceptor because that is what you are returning from the factory

Comment: Yes, I'm using http instead of httpInterceptor in my calls this.http.request(path, requestOptions)....., but it seems that still needs the provider "inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for HttpInterceptor".

Comment: Make sure you aren't trying to inject `HttpInterceptor` anywhere. You should only try to inject `Http`